# Is there a way to show only the values of certain coefficients in red?

Tags: coefficients

I would like to display the color in red if the coefficient value is 2 in the next polynomial.

[image]

But now, the coefficients and orders are all red.

[image]

Is there a way to show only the values of certain coefficients in red?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already noted in the comment:

```
Factor[x^165 - 1] /. Times[2, a_] :> Times[Style[2, Red, Bold, 24], a] // Last
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I solved it well.